# How to obtain Facebook page access_token without logging in or having user interaction

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-authentication

I have been reading the Facebook documentation and I must be missing something, as I just cant understand how to get the access token for a page without actually logging in first.  I am trying to create a PHP function using the PHP facebook API so that when I add new stories or tutorials on my site, my site's apps can then automatically post as the page a blurb about them on myy facebook page.

I have this function working but only when I get the access token from the Graph API Explorer, though the access tokens expire in about an hour.  I can't seem to figure out how to programatically obtain the access_token for the page and query for a new one each time from within my PHP scripts so they don't expire and do not require user interaction.

```
    function post_to_facebook($title, $message, $link, $picture) {

            require '../facebook/src/facebook.php';

            $page_token = 'xxx';

            $page_id = 'xx';

            $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                    'appId'  => '<app_id>',
                    'secret' => '<app_secret>',
                    'cookie' => false,
            ));

            $facebook->setAccessToken($page_token);

            try {
                    $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/feed', 'POST', array(
                                            'caption' => $title,
                                            'link' => $link,
                                            'message' => $message,
                                            'picture' => $picture
                                     ));

            } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
                    error_log($e->getType());
                    error_log($e->getMessage());

                    return false;
            }

            return true;
    }
```

Can someone explain how I can go about retrieving the access token without manually having to look it up via graph api explorer or having a user login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.

The only correct (and legal) way to achieve the access token is with user interaction (through login process).

Comment: Damn. I would have thought that with a app id and app secret, I could at least be able to interact with my site's FB page without user interaction. I read somewhere that page access tokens do not expire? I have not found that to be the case, but I may be looking in the wrong places.  Do you know anything about this?

Comment: @John Tangale: access tokens expire in 60 days: http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: The ones that I received from the graph api explorer only lasted an hour.  Will play with it some more.

Comment: @John Tangale: that's right - you need to extend its expiration explicitly. See the "Scenario 4" at http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token

Comment: I have been reading extensively on this.  For whatever reason I cant seem to create an extended token. Regardless, what I am trying to do is what is state in scenario 5 where I can get a page token that does not expire.  It appears from the above facebook link that scenario 5 should be able to work for me, if I can figure out how to get it properly.

Comment: @John Tangale: it's probably a good idea to create separate question with a correspondent code. I cannot guess what exactly you're doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks again. I took your suggestion and posted the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770720/how-to-create-a-non-expiring-facebook-page-token-as-described-in-the-removal-of