# How to create a non-expiring Facebook page token as described in the Removal of offline_access permission doc

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I am trying to create a non-expiring page token that I can use on my site to make posts on my Facebook page.  According to scenario 5 in this document I should be able to do this:

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

My problem is that when I generate the page tokens, they expire in 1 hour.

What I am doing is using this code to display my user access token when I login.  I think this is the same token provided by graph api explorer, but I am unsure.

```
require '../src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'app_id',
  'secret' => 'app_secret',
));   

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }   
}     

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl( array(

                'scope'         => 'read_stream,publish_stream,publish_actions,manage_pages,email,user_checkins',
                ));
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
echo $loginUrl;

$me = $facebook->api('/me');

?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>php-sdk</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>php-sdk</h1>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>PHP Session</h3>
    <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

      <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

I then use that token in this graph api command:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=<access_token>
```

This gives me a list of all my pages and apps and their respective page/app tokens.

I then take the page token I want to use and check with the Facebook Access Token Debugger and it shows it has an expiration of 1 hour.  So I use the following command to try and exchange it for a 60 day token as described in the first URL i posted:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=access_token
```

The command just gives me the error: "message": "An unknown error has occurred.","type": "OAuthException", "code": 1.

I then thought maybe because my user access token is not long lived, it wont generate a long lived page token.  So I used my user token with the same command to extend it and it just returns the same token back with the expiration not extended.

Can anyone offer some insight as to what I am doing wrong and how I can create this non-expiring page token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the instructions again carefully - based on your description you're:

- Getting a short user token
- Getting a short page token from /me/accounts
- Attempting to extend the short page token

What you should be doing is:

- Getting a short user token (if client side auth)
- Exchanging that for a long user token (or you'll already have a long user token if you used the server side oauth flow)
- Using the long user token to retrieve the (long) page access token

Comment: Unfortunately this is just not working for me.  I used the server side example from here and retrieve a user token for my account: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/. When I check in the token debugger this token is still only valid for an hour. I check /me/accounts and the page token is for one hour as well.  If i try to exchange my 1 hour user token to a long lived one, it just returns the same token with the same expiration.  At a complete loss as everything I am reading shows that it should work.  I think the problem is that FB wont give me a long lived token.

Comment: And you've definitely changed the migration setting for your app so that `offline_access` is no longer available?

Comment: Yup, I just figured it out though.  Even though I specified in my app that I do not wish to use offline_access, it still wouldn't give me a long lived token.  As this was an old app and the app was not in use by anything else, I deleted it and created a new app.  Once I did that, I was able to get the long lived token.  So there is something buggy going on with disabling offline access. Thanks again for your help.